# UITableViewController and custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, iboutlet

Have couple of questions

1. When I place a UITableViewController on the storyboard, and wish to work with static cells must I create a class deriving from UITableViewController or can I only create a class deriving from UITableViewCell for the custom cell?
2. I created a custom UITableViewCell placed number of controls on it and tried dragging with control pressed to create an outlet but couldn't, any ideas why?
3. If I wish each cell to have different controls and behavior can I set each cell a different custom UITableViewCell and if so how does the UITableViewController initialize it? do I need to load it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

1) The cell must be a subclass of UITableViewCell.

2) No, I don't know why that didn't work, it should. Where were you trying to make the connection to? The cell or the table view controller?

3) Yes, I think this is the best way to do it. Have a different custom cell class for each different kind of cell, and make IBOutlets from the custom cell to its controls. Then just make one IBOutlet from the table view controller to the cell itself (you can then refer to the controls with something like self.cellType1.label1 ...). You don't need to do anything to initialize the cells if they're made in the storyboard.

Comment: I'm trying to create the IBOutlets in the custom UITableViewCell

Comment: @liva, do you have a question about that? You should be able to do that from your custom cell class to the controls in your cell. Make sure you change the class of the cell in IB to your custom class first.